# count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (laravel getting error)

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

**I want to enter an multiple field entered data in table with for loop
but i am getting an error in the post method.**

***error is***

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

**controller code :-**

```
$degree = $request->degree;
            for($i=0;$i<count($degree);$i++){
                $edu = new education;
                $edu->degree = $request->degree[i];
                $edu->clg = $request->clg[i];
                $edu->yoc = $request->yoc[i];
                $edu->save();
            }
```

so, please suggest me what i can do.

Comment: `dd($degree)` is it array or not ?

Comment: yes it is array enterd dynamically added value it is

Comment: what is the result of `dd($degree)` ?

Comment: array result enterd dynamically value will shown

Comment: double check your `$request->degree` : 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php , with php version > 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here not at all big problem,
*you can not use count for the one value the array is required for
that i think that you have not been enterd dynamically many values it can be 0*

***so replace code in your controller:-***

```
$degree = $request->degree;
        if($degree > 0)
        {
            for($i=0;$i<count($degree);$i++){
                $edu = new education;
                $edu->degree = $request->degree[i];
                $edu->clg = $request->clg[i];
                $edu->yoc = $request->yoc[i];
                $edu->save();
            }
        }
```

*here i have used $degree if its value is greater then 0 that means
if it has value count grater then one then you can only go for loop and add value to database
otherwise it will be not go in for loop*